# How can I dynamically generate components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to be able to generate a certain number of components (all similar) according to a value chosen in a select element.

I tried to generate this by creating an array of components whose size is the selected number. When I select a number it launch a handle function which changes the selected number in the creation.

```
handle = selected => {
  this.state.number= selected.value;
  this.forceUpdate();
};

render() {
  return( 
   <Select onChange={this.handle} options = { ... }/>
   {[...Array(this.state.number)].map(e => { return ( <TestComponent /> 
); })}
  )
}
```

It loads the first component because the number is initialized to `1` but when I select another number `2,3,4,5,...` it doesn't render the new components.

Comment: you should always update a state variable by using this.setState() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function like below:

```
makeComponentList=(num)=>{
    let i=0,arr=[];
    for(;i<num;i++){
        arr.push(<TestComponent key={i} />)
    }
    return arr;
}

handle = selected => {
    this.setState({number:selected.value});
}

render() {
    return(
        <React.Fragment>
            <Select onChange={this.handle} options = { ... }/>
            {this.makeComponentList(this.state.number)}
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

Comment: Your code works but for a reason i don't know if i choose 1 then 2 it doesn't recalculate the first one (i change the class if they are more than one for the display). It keep the first one with the class A then add others with the class B. If i directly choose 2 the both will have the class B. Do you know what is happening here ? Thanks.

Comment: React does not mount component again, if it is already mounted. It will only re-render it. So when you are selecting 1 and then 2, first component is already there. So it is getting re-rendered. However, on directly selecting 2, both the components mount.

Answer (score 0):

You don't update the state so `this.state.number` value is always set to its initialized value:

```js
handle = selected => {
  this.setState({ number: selected.value }); // Will re-render the component
  this.forceUpdate();
};

render() {
  return( 
    <>
      <Select onChange={this.handle} />
      {[...Array(this.state.number)].map((e, i) => (
        <TestComponent key={i} />
                     // ^ Add a unique key
      ))}
    </>
  )
}
```